# How SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT works in setsockopt?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I am following a socket programming [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/) and the following code came up

```
// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, sizeof(opt)
```

From [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) I see that the third parameter of setsocketopt is an integer which represents option name. After googling about setsockopt I found that almost everywhere only one of SO_REUSEADDR or SO_REUSEPORT is used with setsockopt. In socket.h file value of SO_REUSEPORT is 15 and value of SO_REUSEADDR is 2. My question is what is the purpose of bitwise OR operation in the above code?

Answer (score 3):

That example is incorrect - or, at least, that construct is non-portable. It appears that BSD-ish Unixes (including MacOS) define those options to be bitmasks, in which case, presumably you can get away with bitwise OR'ing them together. However, `setsockopt()` is a Posix-specified function. 
See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsockopt.html, wherein it says:

> The *option_name* argument specifies a **single option** to set.

You should always call `setsockopt()` separately for each option you want to set:

```
// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));
setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```