# Connection refused in socket programming in c linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

I have wrote simple socket programming in c in for Handle multiple socket connections client and sever.

But when I run it, client showed that connection refused error.

**Server side**

```
/**
    Handle multiple socket connections with select and fd_set on Linux
*/
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>   //close
#include <arpa/inet.h>    //close
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h> //FD_SET, FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO macros
 
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define PORT 8889

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[30] , max_clients = 30 , activity, i , valread , sd;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
     
    char buffer[1025];  //data buffer of 1K
     
    //set of socket descriptors
    fd_set readfds;
     
    //a message
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";
 
    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }
     
    //create a master socket
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0) 
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    //set master socket to allow multiple connections , this is just a good habit, it will work without this
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    //type of socket created
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
     
    //bind the socket to localhost port 8888
    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) 
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);
    
    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     
    //accept the incoming connection
    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");
    
    while(TRUE) 
    {
        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
 
        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;
        
        //add child sockets to set
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_socket[i];
            
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
            
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if(sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }
 
        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
   
        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
        {
            printf("select error");
        }
         
        //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
         
            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
       
            //send new connection greeting message
            if( send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) ) 
            {
                perror("send");
            }
             
            puts("Welcome message sent successfully");
             
            //add new socket to array of sockets
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
            {
                //if position is empty
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
         
        //else its some IO operation on some other socket :)
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];
             
            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds)) 
            {
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the incoming message
                if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
                     
                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    close( sd );
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }
                 
                //Echo back the message that came in
                else
                {
                    //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end of the data read
                    buffer[valread] = '\0';
                    send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
    return 0;
}
```

**Client side**

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8889 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    
    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I compile and run the code getting ***Connection refused***

**Compile**

```
gcc server1.c -o server1
gcc client2.c -o client2
```

**Run**

```
./client2 127.0.0.1
Client Error: Connection Failed.: Connection refused
binded successfully
```

Comment: I see you building both the client and server code, then starting the client program. But when and where do you start the *server* program?

Comment: And why is the client binding the socket? That's supposed to be done in the server only.

Comment: sorry edit the client code

Comment: however as @Someprogrammerdude mentioned, the compiled server binary is not started in this example.

Comment: @springe can you please elaborate how to start server binary

Comment: ... the same way you run any program? Though probably you'd want to do so in the background or in another terminal.

Comment: The client program is a good [mcve]  now, but the output you show no longer matches the code. If you radically alter the code, remember to update output (expected and actual) as well.

Comment: By the way you have a serious flaw in the server program. What if `read` fails and returns `-1`? You don't handle that case, leading to undefined behavior and possible crashes.

Comment: @kanchanadisanayaka You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57732351/7508077)